# Como puedo mostrar preguntas dentro de mi juego en unity

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, unity, unity2d

Buenas tengo una duda como puedo hacer para que en mi videojuego me muestre mis preguntas que tengo almacenadas en i php dentro de mi videojuego pero que me las muestre por nivel de manera automatica que detecte mi nivel en el que estoy por ejemplo si estoy en la scena 1-1 que me muestre las preguntas de esa scena y si estoy en la scena 1-2 me envie las preguntas de esa scena, este es mi codigo con el cual muestro las preguntas dentro del juego pero al momento de que yo llego al nivel 2 me sigue mostrando las preguntas de la escena 1-1 en lugar de mostrarme las preguntas de la escena 1-2, mi codigo que proporcione me las muestra solo si le cambio el 1 por el 2 en esta linea de codigo "public static int nivelActual = 1;".
Pero lo que yo quiero es que lo realize demanera automatica sin que yo este deteniendo el juego y este yo cambiandole el 1 por el 2 o 3 etc., Alguien podria decirme como podria yo hacerle gracias.

```
public static int nivelActual = 1;

[ContextMenu("Descargar PreguntasDos")]
public void DescargarPreguntas()
{
    StartCoroutine(CorrutinaDescargarPreguntas());

}
private IEnumerator CorrutinaDescargarPreguntas()
{
    Debug.Log("Corrutina descargar preguntas ");
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    //string nivelActual = "nivel1";
    UnityWebRequest web = UnityWebRequest.Get("http://localhost/Preguntas/pedirPreguntas2.php?nivel=" + nivelActual);
    idPregunta++;
    yield return web.SendWebRequest();
    //esperamos a que vuelva...
    //volvio
    if (web.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError && web.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ProtocolError)
    {
        Debug.Log(web.downloadHandler.text);
        procesarDatos(web);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log(web.downloadHandler.text);
        procesarDatos(web);
    }
}
[ContextMenu("Procesar Preguntas recibidasDos")]
public void procesarDatos(UnityWebRequest web)
{
    string textoOriginal = web.downloadHandler.text;
    partes = textoOriginal.Split(',');
    totalPreguntasNube = partes.Length;
    Debug.Log("*******Longitud del arreglo(Total preguntas de la nube): " + totalPreguntasNube);
    string[] lista = new string[totalPreguntasNube];

    for (int i = 0; i < totalPreguntasNube; i++)
    {
        lista[i] = partes[i];
        Debug.Log("Dentro de procesar datos: ");
        Debug.Log("Lista[" + i + "]=" + lista[i]);
        Debug.Log("Dentro de procesar datos: ");
    }
    numPreg = lista[1];
    //crear Areglos para llenar preguntas y respuestas
    int.TryParse(numPreg, out numeroPreguntasNube);
    Debug.Log("Total de preguntas de la tabla: " + numeroPreguntasNube);
    HistorialPreguntas.totalPreguntasGlobal = numeroPreguntasNube;
    crearArreglos(lista);
}
```

Este es mi php el cual mando a traer en esta linea de codigo "UnityWebRequest.Get("http://localhost/Preguntas/pedirPreguntas2.php?nivel=" + nivelActual);" no se si tenga que cambiarle algo a mi php.

```
<?php
include("conexion.php");

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
   $link = Conectarse();
   $nivel = isset($_GET['nivel']) ? intval($_GET['nivel']) : 1;

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'){
   $link=Conectarse();
     $contador=0;
     $listaCalif=array();
     $listaX="";
     $resultado=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * from preguntas,respuestas
      WHERE preguntas.idPregunta=respuestas.fk_idPregunta AND preguntas.nivel = 
     $nivel;") or die($link);
 if(mysqli_affected_rows($link)>0){
   while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
     $numRenglones = mysqli_num_rows( $resultado );
    $listaCalif[$contador]['idPregunta']=$row['idPregunta'];
    $listaCalif[$contador]['pregunta']=utf8_encode($row['pregunta']);
    $listaCalif[$contador]['c1']=utf8_encode($row['c1']);
    $listaCalif[$contador]['c2']=utf8_encode($row['c2']);
    $listaCalif[$contador]['c3']=utf8_encode($row['c3']);
    $listaCalif[$contador]['rc']=utf8_encode($row['rc']);
    $listaX=$listaX.",".$numRenglones.",".$row['idPregunta'].","
    .utf8_encode($row['pregunta']).","
    .utf8_encode($row['c1']).",".utf8_encode($row['c2']).",".utf8_encode($row['c3']).","
    .utf8_encode($row['rc']);
     $contador=$contador+1;
   }
    print json_encode($listaX);
  }else
      print json_encode(array('estado'=>'2','mesanje'=>'No hay registros'));
  }
  }
  ?>
```

Este es mi codigo cuando realizo el cambio de escena al terminar de contestar mis preguntas en la escena Preguntas1

```
//CAMBIO DE ESCENA DEPENDIENDO LA CALIFICACION
        int currentSceneIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
        if (c >= 70)
        {
            // Si la calificación es mayor o igual a 70, espera 5 segundos y luego carga la escena "Victory" (o su índice correspondiente)
            StartCoroutine(EsperarCambioEscena("Victory"));
        }
        else
        {
            // Si la calificación es menor a 70, espera 5 segundos y luego carga la escena "1-1" (o su índice correspondiente)
            StartCoroutine(EsperarCambioEscena("1-1"));
        }
    }
}//fin OnCollisionEnter2D
private IEnumerator EsperarCambioEscena(string nombreEscena)
{
    // Si ya se realizó el cambio de escena, salimos de la corrutina para evitar cambios adicionales.
    if (cambioDeEscenaRealizado)
    {
        yield break;
    }
    // Esperar 5 segundos
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
    // Cambiar a la escena indicada
    SceneManager.LoadScene(nombreEscena);
    // Marcamos que se ha realizado el cambio de escena
    cambioDeEscenaRealizado = true;
}
public void OnEnable()
{
    // Reiniciar valores antes de mostrar las preguntas
    HistorialPreguntas.ReiniciarValoresGlobales();
}
```

Y este es otro cambio de escena cuando termino mi nivel 1-1

```
public string levelToLoad;

public void EndLevel()
{
    StartCoroutine(EndLevelCo());
}
public IEnumerator EndLevelCo()
{
    AudioManager.instance.PlayerLevelVictory();

    PlayerController.instance.stopInput = true;

    CamaraController.instance.stopFollow = true;

    UIController.instance.levelCompleteText.SetActive(true);

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.5f);

    UIController.instance.FadeToBlack();

    yield return new WaitForSeconds((1f / UIController.instance.fadeSpeed)+ .25f);

    PlayerPrefs.SetInt(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name + "_unlocked", 1);

    PlayerPrefs.SetString("CurrentLevel", SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name + "_gems", gemsCollected);
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name + "_time", timeInLevel);
    
    SceneManager.LoadScene(levelToLoad);
}
```

Comment: Todo ese código que has puesto es irrelevante para tu pregunta. ¿Donde está el código cuando pasas de nivel?

Comment: Gracias por la observacion ya realize una actualizacion de los cambios de escena que se realizan

Comment: En el primero código como se llama esa clase y ese script donde lo has puesto (a cual gameobject) ?

Comment: En el primer codigo la clase se llama PlayerController al igual que el script